# Jquery plugin function unavailable after DOM changed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having a weird problem and not sure how to fix it.
My page loads a plugin in the $(function() event. There's a button on the page that hides the 1st DIV (that contains the rendered plugin) and loads contents from another html page into a 2nd DIV.  The new content in the 2nd DIV has a "Cancel" button that hides the 2nd DIV and shows the original 1st DIV.

Everything's working fine - but the DOM lost the plugin functions, so the plugin doesn't work correctly anymore. The plugin is trying to load functions in teh plugin (ie: $.fn.myplugin = function()...).

here's some PSEUDO code

First Page.....

```
$function() { 
    //Load plugin
    $("div1").theplugin();

    $("button1").click(function() {
        $("div1").hide();
        $.get("2ndpage.html", function (data) { $("div2").html(data);  });
    }); 
};
```

Second Page.....

```
$function() { 
    $("button2").click(function() {
        $("div2").hide();
        $("div1").show();
    }); 
};
```

....At this point if i click on button2, it does hide DIV2 and shows DIV1  - and DIV1 is still in the last state before i click button1, but none of the plugin's functions are in the DOM.

Anyone know how to address this?
Thanks in advance!

***More info***
I placed watches on plugin's function (the one in question), and it changes from it's definition to "undefined" when the code hits this point:

```
$.get("2ndpage.html", function (data) { 
    $("div2").html(data);  //HERE
});
```

It's almost like the DOM is being replaced with the page called by .get() - but this doesn't seem right - or is it?  Maybe there's a special way to kill the content from page 2 so that the DOM goes back to the state it was in before .get() was called?  I dunno, thos problem is bizarre and is fustrating :)
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try below one for your button's **click event**.

Here I have applied only for 1 button.You should apply it for both buttons and check the out come.

```
$("button2").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
   $("div2").hide();
   $("div1").show();
   return false; //to prevent the browser actually following the links!
});
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: didn't work - function still becomes "undefined" after new page loads :(